# How to change visibility of an element on current page?

Tags: javascript, visibility, hidden, visible

Some currently building a little interface for a project and I'm stuck at a point. Currently I have a function `setPage()` that set a `.current` class to the active link.

But... I would like to change the visibility a `<p>` so it become active when it is the current page.

The `<p>` is hidden by default in the CSS.

Here is the HTML (BTW, index : 1,2,3,4... Are only for testing)

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="activemenu.js"></script>
</head>

<html>
<body>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">List Item 1<p>1042</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="index2.html">List Item 2<p>1042</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="index3.html">List Item 3<p>1042</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="index4.html">List Item 4<p>1042</p></a></li>
    </ul>
    <script language="javascript">setPage()</script>
    <div id="newalbumtxt"><a href="#">Create new album</a></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And here is the `setPage()` fonction

```
function extractPageName(hrefString)
{
    var arr = hrefString.split('/');
    return  (arr.length < 2) ? hrefString : arr[arr.length-2].toLowerCase() + arr[arr.length-1].toLowerCase();
}
function setActiveMenu(arr, crtPage)
{
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(extractPageName(arr[i].href) == crtPage)
        {
            if (arr[i].parentNode.tagName != "DIV")
            {
                    arr[i].className = "current";
                    arr[i].parentNode.className = "current";
            }
        }
    }
}
function setActiveNbImg(arr, crtPage)
{
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(extractPageName(arr[i].href) == crtPage)
        {
            if (arr[i].parentNode.tagName != "DIV")
            {
                    arr[i].className = "current";
                    arr[i].parentNode.className = "current";
            }
        }
    }
}

function setPage()
{
    hrefString = document.location.href ? document.location.href : document.location;

    if (document.getElementById("menu") !=null )
    setActiveMenu(document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("a"), extractPageName(hrefString));
}

function setNbImg()
{
    hrefString = document.location.href ? document.location.href : document.location;

    if (document.getElementById("menu") !=null )
        setActiveNbImg(document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("p"), extractPageName(hrefString));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
a p {
  display: none;
}

a.current p {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add another class to the elements or modify the current one to include a `display` or `visibility` declaration:

```
a p
{
    display: none;
}

.current
{
    display: block;
}
```

Or:

```
a p
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.current
{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

`display` alters the way your element is displayed, this has multiple values such as `inline`, `inline-block`, `block`, `table`, `table-cell` etc. When set to `none` the element is no longer rendered at all and the space it would have taken up is free again. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display)

`visibility` simply changes whether the element is visible or not, but the main difference from `display` is that the space taken up by the element is not reclaimed, much like using `position: relative`. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/visibility)

Comment: I found a solution !

Was really simple : 

In CSS just change the formating : a.current p {
visibility: visible;
}